# Deploy gatsby site to netlify with --prefix-paths

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I'm trying to deploy a blog site built with Gatsby to Netlify. The thing is, I want to serve the site from /blog.
Following the docs, I changed the gatsby-config.js to include pathPrefix like so:

```
module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: `/blog`,
  siteMetadata: {...},
  plugins: [...]
}
```

Next, I changed my build command to include --prefix-paths:

```
gatsby build --prefix-paths
```

When I run the site locally using `gatsby serve --prefix-paths` everything works fine. However, after I deployed to netlify the site is still being served from root / and not from /blog.
My netlify.toml:

```
[build]
  Command = "npm run build"
  Functions = "lambda"
  Publish = "public"
```

The build command frum netlify.toml runs the command from package.json which is this:

```
"build": "run-p build:**",
"build:app": "gatsby build --prefix-paths",
"build:lambda": "netlify-lambda build src/lambda",
```

What am I missing here? Do I need to make some other configuration to netlify or something?

Comment: Do you need to set a `Base directory` under netlify's `Continuous Deployment` menu?

Comment: No, I don't need to set a base directory.

Comment: So, when you download a copy of your build from netlify, are the files not in /blog?  This article's screenshot shows how to download a copy of what's built: https://community.netlify.com/t/common-issue-i-ve-deployed-my-site-but-i-still-see-page-not-found/125 , and this one explains deeply how to debug what is happening during your build in more detail:  https://community.netlify.com/t/common-issue-debugging-site-builds/142

Comment: That's right.. The files are not in /blog.. Someone suggested that I run a package.json script to copy everything inside public into the blog folder when I run the build command. That's what I did using gatsby build --prefix-paths && cd public && mkdir blog && cd public && mv * blog.. Works locally but on netlify it throws a weird error: 10:31:42 AM:   Error: Input file is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone encountering the same issue. I was able to solve this by copying all the files inside the public folder into the "blog" folder like so:

```
"build": "run-p build:**",
"build:app": "npm run clean && gatsby build --prefix-paths && npm run move",
"build:lambda": "netlify-lambda build src/lambda",
"move": "cd public && mkdir blog | mv * blog"
```

I added the move command to package.json and I execute it after the build. I'm not sure if that's how I'm suppose to do it but after doing some research (I also found a started that was doing this) I think it's ok.

Now that the files are served from "/blog" everything works fine.

Comment: I tried what you did, but I failed. The error I received is "missing script: clean". When I remove "npm run clean", I get the following error: "gatsby not found". I'm going crazy. How did you do it :)

Comment: @hkucuk You appear not to have run "npm install clean" or "npm install -g gatsby"

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a main site already running and you want to integrate your gatsby blog into it.

1. In your gatsby blog `gatsby-config.js` file, add:

```
module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: `/blog`,
}
```

2. Always in your gatsby blog, create a `netlify.toml` configuration file at the root of your site with:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/blog/*"
  to = "/:splat"
```

The reason of this redirect is that `--prefix-path` doesn’t change where gatsby stores built files in the build directory. This creates a difference between your blog links, which are prefixed with `/blog` and the path to your files. So you want to tell your site that each url prefixed with `/blog` should point to the files that are in your build directory (under `/` path).

3. In your **main** site, create also a `netlify.toml` configuration file with this redirect rule:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/blog/*"
  to = "https://my-gatsby-blog.netlify.app/:splat"
  status = 200
```

This tells your main site it should redirect to your gatsby blog for every path's url beginning with `/blog/`.