# How to combine 2 Gatsby sites in one domain?

Tags: gatsby, netlify, static-site, jamstack

I want to combine 2 Gatsby sites in one domain, for example, Gatsby1 (landing page) in mydomain.com, and Gatsby2 (blog) in mydomain.com/blog, how can I do that?

Comment: you could use a subdomain eg: blog.mydomain.com and the configuration is the like other subdomain

Comment: No, I don't want a subdomain

Answer (score 1):

Create two Gatbsy projects. One can be configured from the root `mydomain.com`. One needs to use [path prefixes](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/):

```js
gatsby-config.js

module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: `/blog`,
}
```

When you build you need to use a flag: `gatsby build --prefix-paths`.

Comment: thanks, but it confuses me even more, because it seems similar to basepath, I asked another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60245845/gatsby-whats-the-difference-between-basepath-and-path-prefix

Comment: and using path prefix seems problematic with Netlify, I am trying to avoid this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56425441/deploy-gatsby-site-to-netlify-with-prefix-paths?rq=1