# Gatsby: what's the difference between basepath and path prefix?

Tags: gatsby, jamstack

I don't understand the difference between `basepath` and `path prefix` in **Gatsby**, and when to use each feature

Basepath: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-seven/

Path prefix: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/

Answer (score 1):

**TL:DR**

`pathPrefix` has much more impact on your site — it add a prefix to the generated url of all your pages and assets. `basePath` is just a helper for generating slug from your filesystem — In my experience with Gatsby I rarely use it at all.

---

### pathPrefix

It appends a prefix to url of all your pages & assets. This way, you can deploy Gatsby site as a sub directory of another site.

```
Without Prefix             | With 'blog' Prefix
---------------------------|--------------------------------
myblog.com/                | myblog.com/blog
myblog.com/hello/          | myblog.com/blog/hello
myblog.com/image-123.png   | myblog.com/blog/image-123.png
```

---

### basePath

It's an option of `createFilePath` which helps you create slug from your project structure. It doesn't affect whether you're serving your Gatsby from root or not.

If your project directory is like this:

```
<root>
  |--content
  |     |--writing
  |     |    `--page1.md
  |     `--images
  |          `--cat.md
  |
  |--gatsby-config.js
 ...
```

And you set this in your gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/content`,
        name: 'content'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then `createFilePath` will return this slug for your file: `writing/page1/`, which maybe not what you want. Maybe you want it to be `/page1/`. In this case, setting `basePath` to `writing` will return `/page1/`.

Comment: it's not my experience with `basePath`: It adds 'blog/' to all URLs, including blog posts living in the `blog` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding path generation in Gatsby is tricky, because there are many factors at play:

- how do you set up your project directory?
- how do you configure `gatsby-source-filesystem`?
- in case you create pages programmatically in `gatsby-node.js`, what did you pass to the `path` field of the `createPages` API?

Since the OP said that all of their site URLs were prefixed with `blog/`, that means they had set up `path prefix` to serve the whole site at the `blog/` path relative to the root of their domain. `basePath` has nothing to do with this.

Unless you are very sure that you want to serve your whole Gatsby site at a different path other than the root `/` of the domain, I suggest you don't do anything to `path prefix`.

Continuing from Derek Nguyen's example:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/content`,
        name: 'content'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In `gatsby-node.js`, when you call the function `createFilePath` of `gatsby-source-filesystem`, you will get relative paths to the two Markdown files as followed:

- `/writing/page1`
- `/images/cat`

Then, if you create pages followed this [Gatsby tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/tutorial/part-seven/), those files should be generated into two HTML pages at:

- `localhost:8000/blog/writing/page1`
- `localhost:8000/blog/images/cat`

In this case, whether you use `basePath` or not doesn't matter. It is simply a helper function to remove a common path from your file path. You can't remove `/blog` because it is set up by `path prefix`.

However, suppose you decide to move `cat.md` from `/images` directory to `/writing`, basePath can come in handy. Actually, you should, because there is no reason why `cat.md` should be under `/images` directory.

```
<root>
  |--content
  |     |--writing
  |     |    `--page1.md
             `--cat.md
  |
  |--gatsby-config.js
 ...
```

Now, the path generated for each Markdown file will changed:

- `/writing/page1/`
- `/writing/cat/`

You can remove `writing` from the urls by passing it to `basePath` as followed.

```
const { createFilePath } = require('gatsby-source-filesystem')
exports.onCreateNode({ node, getNode }) => {
  if (node.internal.type === 'MarkdownRemark') {
    console.log(createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: 'writing' }))
  }
}
```

Restart the development server and you should see your markdown pages will be served at:

- `localhost:8000/blog/page1`
- `localhost:8000/blog/cat`